# Describe symbol properties in elisp

Tags: elisp, emacs24

```
:bar
(describe :bar)
```

must display the values for these properties:

```
NAME, VALUE, FUNCTION, PLIST, PACKAGE
```

Any function in elisp that does this? if not inbuilt, how can i add Common lisp's describe functionality into elisp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're available individually, via `symbol-*` functions:

```el
(symbol-name SYMBOL)
(symbol-value SYMBOL)
(symbol-function SYMBOL)
(symbol-plist SYMBOL)
```

By `PACKAGE` I'm not sure whether you mean ELPA packages in Emacs, or Common Lisp packages. Elisp doesn't have the latter, and the former isn't stored, although you could derive it in many cases based on the file which defined the symbol, which is:

```el
(symbol-file SYMBOL &optional TYPE)
```